# Java Spring Boot OpenApi 3 - How to add description for RequestBody?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I want to have a **description** for `RequestBody` in spring boot openapi 3 .
so i make my code like this :

```js
@PostMapping(produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Book> addBook(
            @Schema(
                    description = "Book to add.",
                    required=true,
                    schema=@Schema(implementation = Book.class))
            @Valid @RequestBody Book book
    ) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(bookRepository.add(Book));
}
```

`RequestBody` **description** is `Book to add.`
My desire UI is like this :

[image: desire]

But nothings happen ! There is no **description** in my UI.

**description** was added to `Schemas` panel `Book` entity !!!
[image: result]

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From your Code Snippet it seems to me as if your description actually belongs into the @RequestBody Annotation instead of the @Schema Annotation.

With @Schema you define and describe your Models but what you actually want to do is to describe the parameter in the context of your operation.

Try something along the lines of:

```
@PostMapping(produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Book> addBook(
            @RequestBody(description = "Book to add.", required = true,
                        content = @Content(
                                schema=@Schema(implementation = Book.class)))   
            @Valid Book book
    ) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(bookRepository.add(Book));
}
```

Comment: @RequestBody does not have description property.it just have required property.

Comment: Are you using the right Annotation ? https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.1.5/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/parameters/RequestBody.html
Maybe you are using the springframework.web... Annotation.
Maybe your dependency to swagger-annotations points to an outdated version.

Comment: yes my friend . thanks alot . we have two RequestBody.   1) io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody and 2) org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody . I should use io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to Gabriel Frassl.

we should use

> `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody`

instead of

> `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody`

so we have good stuffs like `description` , `content` , ...

Comment: But when you use the @RequestBody from swagger the JSON mapping does not work anymore, the properties are just null in the controller, do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Use both of them together: `@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(description = "", required = true, content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = MyClass.class))) @RequestBody MyClass body`

Answer (score 3):

To add to the `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody` solution that was pointed out in other answers:

- Mind that you do not want to remove the `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation` RequestBody Annotation when you add the swagger annotation. This might break the endpoint's boddy binding.
- You can also add a `@Parameter(description = "...")` (i.e. `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter`) to **any** parameter of your endpoint. This works also for `@RequestHeader`, `@PathVariable`,... which might not come with a handy `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters` version like `RequestBody`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@PostMapping(produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Book> addBook(
        @RequestBody(description = "Book to add.", required = true,
                    content = @Content(
                            schema=@Schema(implementation = Book.class)))   
        @Valid @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody Book book
) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(bookRepository.add(Book));
}
```

For that I add @RequestBody from springframework. It works to me.